# $χ(G) ≤ k_1k_2$ if and only if $G = G_1 ∪ G_2$, where $χ(Gi) ≤ k_i$, $i = 1, 2$.'' (S.A. Burr)

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I don't have an idea how to do this. Can anyone help?

''Show that $χ(G) ≤ k_1k_2$ if and only if $G = G_1 ∪ G_2$, where $χ(Gi) ≤ k_i$, $i = 1, 2$.'' (S.A. Burr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is my idea. You use the colors on $G_1$ and $G_2$ to make pairs of colors and use these pairs as colors on $G$.

Assume you got two graphs $G_i, i= 1,2$ on a vertex set $V$ with $\chi_i=\chi(G_i)$. Choose colorings $c_i(v)$. Define the coloring $c(v):=(c_1(v),c_2(v))$ on $G$. You got at most $\chi_1\chi_2$ different pairs.

[image]

The other way around was a bit more tricky. Lets consider $\chi(G)\leq k_1k_2$ and choose a coloring. Partition the set $C$ of colors on $G$ into $k_1$ sets $C_1,...,C_{k_1}$, each one of at most $k_2$ colors. Lets say the colors in set $C_j$ are $c_1^{(j)},...,c_{K}^{(j)},K\leq k_2$. Now you can interprete the color $c_i^{(j)}$ as the pair $(c_i^1,c_j^2)$ with new colors $c_m^1,m=1,...,K$ and $c_n^2,n=1,...,K',K'\leq k_2$. Spoken simply, you decompose a color into two colors dependent on the set in which you put it and which number you assigned it inside the set. Now you can go backwards and construct $G_1$ and $G_2$ using only the colors $c_m^1$ and $c_n^2$ as seen in the figure below.

[image]

The partition of the color set naturally induces a partition of the vertex set $V$: two vertices belong to the same class, if and only if their respective colors belong to the same set. Then choose $G_1$ to only contain the *inner edges* of these vertex partition classes, and $G_2$ to only the edges *between* the classes.

Of course a rigorous proof would have to contain some reasoning that all these constructions yield feasible colorings, but I think the main task was having this idea of pairing colors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One question...how it will be possible to do this (using the question I've posted above):                                                                       ''Deduce that the union of a $k$-degenerate graph and an $l$-degenerate graph is $(k + 1)( l + 1)$-colourable.''

Comment: A $k$-degenerate graph $G$ will have $\chi(G)\leq k+1$. The rest is a direct consequence of your question.

Comment: Can we say:                                                                                                  ''A  k-degenerate graph $G_1$ will have $χ(G_1)≤k+1$ and an l-degenerate graph $G_2$ will have $χ(G_2)≤l+1$. By the facts that if $G=G_1 U G_2$, then $χ(G)≤k_1 k_2$, we can say that an union of the two graphs will be $(k+1)(l+1)$-colourable.''                                          Would that be ok or not really?

Comment: I think this should be ok.

Comment: Thank you a lot for such a detailed full explanation with added images.